# Android: Extra from previous activity is null

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send some info back to my main activity, but the value keeps turning out to be null. I know for a fact that the info in my 2nd activity (the one that is passing the info) is not null, since I print it out before hand.

Here is what I have:

Main activity:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, 2ndActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
      //  startActivityForResult(i, 0); I have tried this too, but same result
        onActivityResult(1, RESULT_OK, i);
    }

//allow to receive info from 2nd activity
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           ArrayList<String> list= data.getStringArrayListExtra("info");
            if(list== null)
                System.out.println("ITS NULL\n.\n.");
            else
                System.out.println("ITS ALL GOOOD!\n.\n.");
        }
    }
}
```

2nd activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();//go back to previous intent 
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("info", selectedItems);//selectedItems is an ArrayList of String
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();//go back to the previous page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
  ` startActivity(i); 
  //  startActivityForResult(i, 0); I have tried this too, but same result 
    onActivityResult(1, RESULT_OK, i); `
```

with

`startActivityForResult(i,1)`

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the activity, do that:

```
    i.putExtra("STRINGVARIABLENAME", stringvalue);
```

And call it by doing this in the second activity:

```
    String boobis = getIntent.getStringExtra("STRINGVARIABLENAME"); //Has to be the same as above
```

Now use the variable wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity, why do you manually call onActivityResult? You shouldn't do that. You should just call startActivityForResult(i, 0) and then wait for the second activity to finish, onActivityResult will automatically get called. and the request code needs to match the one you passed in startActivityForResult, which is 0 in this instance.